# Flutter native admob is not working on iPhone

Tags: flutter, admob, native-ads

I added flutter native admob in my app. It's working very well on Android devices but when I try run the app on IOS devices it turns loading screen. I added my code and also screenshot about this issue. How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

```
new Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
                          height: 180,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFE7EFFF),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: NativeAdmob(
                            adUnitID:
                                'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110',
                            loading: Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: Color(0xFFEEA86C),
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE7EFFF),
                              ),
                            ),
                            error: Text('Failed to load the ads'),
                            controller: _controller,
                            type: NativeAdmobType.full,
                            numberAds: 1,
                            options: NativeAdmobOptions(
                                ratingColor: Colors.orange,
                                showMediaContent: true,
                                headlineTextStyle:
                                    NativeTextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ),
                        )
```

This is how it works on Android devices.

[image]

This is how it works on IOS devices.
[image]

Comment: I think you should use ios adsid and factory id.

`adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
            ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110'
            : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511',
        factoryId: 'listTile',`

for more info have a look at [https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7]